# Cookiemanager is returning different cookie parameters depending on the API

Tags: java, android, cookies, android-cookiemanager

I am trying to get the cookie from an URL using `CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url)`. What I have noticed is that for Android 10 the cookie contains `__Host-nc_sameSiteCookielax=true; __Host-nc_sameSiteCookiestrict=true` however for lower APIs those parameters are missing. Where is the difference coming from?

In my case those parameters are absolutely necessary so as of right now I am adding manually for further requests. Is there a better way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is the same issue with Cookies containing the `SameSite` Attribute: [CookieManager.getCookie() always returns null (Version <= API 28 (Pie))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65812748/cookiemanager-getcookie-always-returns-null-version-api-28-pie/65819593#65819593)

Its a Bug in the underlying WebView Implementation.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=780491