# Android CookieManager returns null on API level 28

Tags: android, cookies, webview

My app has a `WebView` that users can download a file from. I have set an `onDownloadListener` that invokes the `DownloadManager` to download the file.
Some files, however, require athentication to access and since authentication is handled using **cookies** I have used the `CookieManager` to get and pass them to the DownloadManager.

This works great for all devices **except** for those running **Android 9** (API level 28). I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65812748/cookiemanager-getcookie-always-returns-null-version-api-28-pie) that there is a **bug** with the CookieManager returning `null` and ignoring `same-site` cookies on Android 9's default WebView version.

I haven't found a fix however and since these cookies are also marked as `http-only` I can't get them using `JavaScript`. I also don't want to remove `http-only` or `same-site` attributes from response or use some other hacky way of implementing this since it will introduce a potential **security risk**.

Comment: I also discovered that it happens on android 8 (WebView 58)